# How can I get my form to post selected value to a new page in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have tried all the solutions I have found online and unfortunately cannot figure this out.

I have this form on one php page. The form populates a drop down menu the name and price of a service. I want the form to post the name and price to the next php page (/FinaliseOrder.php). Here is the first page:

```
    <form method="post" action="/FinaliseOrder.php">
     <!-- form action will go here --> 
     <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2 form-label"><label style="margin-top:7px;">Select Shipping Option:</label></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3">
           <select class="form-control" name="list" title="pick a type">
              <?php if(count($postOpts)) { ?>
              <?php foreach($postOpts as $row) { ?>
              <option value="<?= $row["price"] ?>"><?= $row["name"] ." ($".$row["price"].")" ?></option>
              <?php } ?>
              <?php } else { ?>
              <option value="<?= $post->getDefaultPrice() ?>"><?= "Default Shipping Option - $".$post->getDefaultPrice() ?></option>
              <?php } ?>
           </select>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Confirm</button>
     </div>
  </form>
```

On the /FinaliseOrder.php page, I am using this:

```
    The name is <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
    The price is: <?php echo $_POST["price"]; ?>
```

But they are blank. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$_GET["name"]` to `$_POST["name"]`

use option like that :-

```
<option value="<?php echo $row['name'].'$'.$row['price']; ?>">
<?php 
echo $row['name'] .' ($'.$row['price'].')' ;
?>
</option>
```

or print data like that :-

```
<?php
echo $_POST['list'];
//for print value 
$value=explode("$",$_POST['list']);
echo $value[0]."<br>";
echo $value[1];
?>
```

Comment: use **echo $_POST['list'];**

Comment: And how do i get the name? That just gives me the price

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93690/discussion-between-bandoy123-and-rahautos).

Answer (score 0):

try this code, maybe you need to check if button submit was clicked. I hope this code will solve your problem.

```
<?php

   if(isset['submit']) {
      $name = $_POST['name'];
      $price = $_POST['price'];
      echo "Your name is $name and the price is $price";
   }

?>
```

Comment: to your FinaliseOrder.php

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, you need to get the price and check it in your FinaliseOrder.php, am I correct?

Comment: Yes correct. But the issue is with the form not posting properly/

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="<?= $row["name"].",".$row["price"] ?>"><?= $row["name"] ." ($".$row["price"].")" ?></option>
```

first replace your one line code very next to for each line code with
then in FinaliseOrder.php page write echo $data[0] for getting name and echo $data[1] for getting price